# How to auto verify OTP in React Native on android?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, one-time-password, sms-verification

I am trying to auto verify `otp` using `react-native-sms-retriever` on `android devices`.
I have tried following way to achieve.

```
 import SmsRetriever from 'react-native-sms-retriever';

 // Get the phone number (first gif)
 _onPhoneNumberPressed = async () => {
 try {
 const phoneNumber = await SmsRetriever.requestPhoneNumber();
 } catch (error) {
 console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
 }
 };

 // Get the SMS message (second gif)
 _onSmsListenerPressed = async () => {
 try {
 const registered = await SmsRetriever.startSmsRetriever();
 if (registered) {
 SmsRetriever.addSmsListener(event => {
 console.log(event.message);
 SmsRetriever.removeSmsListener();
 }); 
 }
 } catch (error) {
 console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
 }
 };
```

**Following is my OTP format**

```
OTP for your login to Orgpick is 3242. Please enter OTP  within 10 minutes.
```

Also I have created `sms` format as follows dummy key-`SZ3KPh5voKE` Please guide me with following `sms` format.

**Shall I need to get same format from server end?**

**What changes need to be done at server side?**

```
<#>OTP for your login to Orgpick is 3242. Please enter OTP  within 10 minutes.SZ3KPh5voKE
```

While trying above solution it showing **`time out exception`**

Please help me to get out from it.

Comment: You can use this package [Package link](https://github.com/Bruno-Furtado/react-native-sms-retriever)

Comment: @MohammedAshfaq Can You Read my question again that i have updated

Comment: please checkout this thread https://github.com/Bruno-Furtado/react-native-sms-retriever/issues/4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried two libraries for auto otp verification but none of them worked for me then I have tried with following library its working fine.Please check answer i have uploaded here

[Auto otp verification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58076214/how-to-implement-react-native-otp-retriever-and-generate-hash-key-for-applicatio)

Answer (score 0):

That is basically a key issue. The Hex code key which you are sending in the message may not be correct which is causing this issue. Try generating a perfect key and send it to the message.

Note production key and debug key are different. Your's look like debug key.

https://github.com/Bruno-Furtado/react-native-sms-retriever/issues/4

This issue answer will help you.

Comment: I have encountered the same problem and my issue was this only.

Comment: i have used this `keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore '~\.android\debug.keystore' | xxd -p | tr -d "[:space:]" | echo -n <<<com.sms_listener>>> cat | sha256sum | tr -d "[:space:]-" | xxd -r -p | base64 | cut -c1-11`

Comment: `androiddebugkey`  this is for debug

Comment: I have attached a link above for your reference. Please go to that

Answer (score 0):

Please check your play service is up to date. I had the same problem and fixed it by updating the play service.