# How to Implement react native otp retriever and generate hash key for application

Tags: react-native, one-time-password, sms-verification

**Beginner to React native**

I am trying to verify `OTP` automatically using `react-native-sms-retriever`
I have implemented following example in project

[Example implemented](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-sms-retriever) This exampleis not provudung way to get hash key. you have to get it manually by executing command

When I execute command, it won't ask for password. It should ask [because of here it is](https://github.com/Bruno-Furtado/react-native-sms-retriever/issues/4#issuecomment-508026734)

> I have generated **debug hash key** using bellow command
>   executed in 'java/bin' folder. But its not

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore '~\.android\debug.keystore' | xxd -p | tr -d "[:space:]" | echo -n com.opick.app cat | sha256sum | tr -d "[:space:]-" | xxd -r -p | base64 | cut -c1-11
```

How to generate hash key for release build tried following returns wrong key

```
keytool -exportcert -alias my-key-alias -keystore my-key.keystore | xxd -p | tr -d "[:space:]" | echo -n com.opick.app `cat` | sha256sum | tr -d "[:space:]-" | xxd -r -p | base64 | cut -c1-11
```

I have read document they says you need to add `path` for `release keystore` in above command.for me i is not working please update on same

Main challenge is the generated key is different on `cmd` and `bash`

Comment: What are the problems you face?

Comment: @RishavKumar yor solution giving time out exception on ` SmsRetriever.addSmsListener((event)=>{console.log('registeredOtp'+" "+event.message);}`

Comment: I was waiting for this. Your hash code is incorrect. Please try retrieving correct hex code. It's different for debug build and production build. I have faced this. :)

Comment: I updated my answer, please see. https://github.com/Bruno-Furtado/react-native-sms-retriever/issues/4

Comment: @RishavKumar how to get hash key for release one where to run these command i am running in `java/bin` for release what need to do can u show sample for release

Comment: Just follow the above link it has all your answer

Comment: the solution is only for debug hash key and for release how to add release keystore path

Comment: for release you need to have the path of your production keystore

Comment: @RishavKumar when i add path the command is not executing file path is `E:\ReactNative\opick\android\app\my-key.keystore`

Comment: how about giving a relative path rather than absolute path. Relative path would be : `./android\app\my-key.keystore`

Comment: @RishavKumar something is going wrong because it is not asking for password as here said   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7506392/how-to-create-android-facebook-key-hash/46241386

Comment: That link is for facebook key hash

Comment: @RishavKumar I have tried with this and its working https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-otp-verify

Comment: @RishavKumar the key added in sms will always display in sms or we can hide

Comment: Always, you can't hide

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have tried two three examples but I was not able to get the `hash key` for `release` ad `debug` then I have tried following solution It worked perfectly.
Also you can use this code to get `hash key` and you can continue with your implementation

[react-native-otp-verify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-otp-verify)

> The following code will give you hash key for both release and debug apk just get the key and copy it somewhere for use

```
import RNOtpVerify from 'react-native-otp-verify';

getHash = () =>
   RNOtpVerify.getHash()
  .then(console.log)
  .catch(console.log);

startListeningForOtp = () =>
    RNOtpVerify.getOtp()
    .then(p => RNOtpVerify.addListener(this.otpHandler))
    .catch(p => console.log(p));

otpHandler = (message: string) => {
    const otp = /(\d{4})/g.exec(message)[1];
    this.setState({ otp });
    RNOtpVerify.removeListener();
    Keyboard.dismiss();
  }

 componentWillUnmount() {
   RNOtpVerify.removeListener();
 }
```

Comment: How can I test it is working. I am trying to send the SMS to the mobile from another mobile with the exact format and hash but it's not detecting the OTP.

Comment: why  `const otp = /(\d{4})/g.exec(message)[1]`  keep giving the error `TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating '/(\d{6})/g.exec(message)[1]')`

Comment: @AnujSharma because its nullable, you can also put ! after message to fix this error like this, /(\d{6})/g.exec(message)![1];

Answer (score 1):

```
import SmsRetriever from 'react-native-sms-retriever';

// Get the phone number (first gif)
 _onPhoneNumberPressed = async () => {
  try {
    const phoneNumber = await SmsRetriever.requestPhoneNumber();
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
  }
 };

// Get the SMS message (second gif)
_onSmsListenerPressed = async () => {
  try {
    const registered = await SmsRetriever.startSmsRetriever();
    if (registered) {
      SmsRetriever.addSmsListener(event => {
        console.log(event.message);
        SmsRetriever.removeSmsListener();
      }); 
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
  }
};
```

For timeout error please see : https://github.com/Bruno-Furtado/react-native-sms-retriever/issues/4

Comment: Use this library. I have personally used and got the results

Comment: for this sms permission will be needed?

Comment: Can we upload app on play store with this without violating sms/log permission policy

Comment: Nop, that's why it's needed. No permissions required and play store allows this as this uses google API's

Comment: Sure, well you need to find out your app's production hex key and send that in sms

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199891/discussion-between-sagar-and-rishav-kumar).

Answer (score 0):

There is a great article tutorial for how to implement OTP auto verify in React Native without taking permission.

[Link1](https://dev.to/jyotishman/how-to-auto-read-sms-otp-in-react-native-without-permission-13a6)

But for that you will need to generate the 11 digit unique hash key. You will find that in link2;

[Link2](https://dev.to/jyotishman/how-to-generate-11-char-hash-key-for-sms-retriever-2ag4)

Answer (score -2):

react-native-otp-verify one works like a charm :) . Good thing , it also gives you the hash .. All you need to do is append the hash in the SMS at the end.